# Node.js and error parsing a protocol buffer 

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

Below is my code for trying to parse a protocol buffer from node.js.  It works in python but in node.js I seem to be having issues.  My big concern is am 1) am i getting the payload correct? and 2) Am I using protocol buffers to parse the payload correct.

When I log to the console the payload is sys  so I am assuming that s the prot buffer from the request.  Then I parse the buffer by calling:

```
 bid_request.parse(payload);
```

Here is the code snippet and error:

```
var buffertools = require('buffertools');
var Schema = require('protobuf').Schema; 
var schema = new Schema(fs.readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/test.desc'));

app.post('/n/test', function(req, res){

      var payload = [];
      req.on('data', function (data) {
        payload.push(data);
      });
      console.log(payload);
      req.on('end', function () {
        var payload = buffertools.concat.apply(null, payload);
        console.log(payload);
        console.log('--------------');
        var bid_request = schema['BidRequest'];

        var brr_fu = bid_request.parse(payload);

        // rest of code here

      });

});


libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "BidRequest" because it is missing required fields: id

undefined:1
urn f.call(self,
      ^
Error: Malformed message
    at Function.parse (unknown source)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/bidder.js:80:31)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:130:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1506:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:374:27)
```

I am also curious as to why the payload is a `<SlowBuffer>`

Comment: Looks like the code I gave is working fine. I think the error is on the message producing side. As the decoder states that the message is not correct. Could you show the code that produces the message? Does it put a value in the `id` field when the producer encodes the message?

Comment: THe code is generated by a python script written by goggle the submits a post.  It does work and python can successfully parse the PB.  Just not node.  I wish but cant.

Comment: Also, I installed proto for node from this repo.  https://github.com/englercj/protobuf